# Wordpress: 301 redirect from localhost to domain name

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, amazon-ec2

I put my Wordpress server and a node.js server inside the same AWS EC2 instance. When the node.js server calls the Wordpress server using REST API at http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts, the request is 301 redirected to the domain name of the EC2 instance, e.g. https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts.

Is this an Apache configuration issue or a EC2 setting problem?

```
curl -v http://127.0.0.1/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /wp-json/wp/v2/posts/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.45.0
> Accept: /
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Sun, 03 Nov 2019 05:22:33 GMT
< Server: Apache
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.6
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< X-Redirect-By: WordPress
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=solm9p823bieif699g4ggtqub6; path=/
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Location: http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Cache-Control: s-maxage=10
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

Comment: You need change in database your domain name to localhost. https://wpbeaches.com/updating-wordpress-mysql-database-after-moving-to-a-new-url/

Comment: My wordpress site is publicly accessible so I cant change the domain name in db to localhost.